# Making a nonlinear fit to a set of data points

Tags: plotting, fitting, nonlinear

I have a collection of data

```
 a0b7 = 
   Table[
     {{0.01`, 0.048210580093612655`}, {0.02`, 0.04823954678734667`}, 
      {0.03`, 0.04821555471430313`}, {0.04`, 0.04811564106936836`}, 
      {0.05`, 0.04815182711185681`}, {0.06`, 0.04800244159194423`}, 
      {0.07`, 0.047987407067919395`}, {0.08`, 0.04785766284608522`}, 
      {0.09`, 0.047771957661935774`}, {0.1`, 0.04772401202975343`}, 
      {0.11`, 0.0476528836847016`}, {0.12`, 0.04757077818998488`}, 
      {0.13`, 0.04752808223718771`}, {0.14`, 0.04743123828481375`}, 
      {0.15`, 0.047472879479558236`}, {0.16`, 0.04753933712481332`}, 
      {0.17`, 0.0475047868063725`}, {0.18`, 0.04757767540247086`}, 
      {0.19`, 0.04759783119112234`}, {0.2`, 0.04756174676025805`}, 
      {0.21`, 0.04762931320390573`}}];
```

I'm trying to do a nonlinear fit, below is my code

```
a0b7model = a Exp[-b (x - c)^6] + d Sin[ω x + Φ];
a0b7fit = FindFit[a0b7, a0b7model, {a, b, c, d, ω, Φ}, x]
Show[
  Plot[Evaluate[model /. a0b7fit], {x, 0.01, 0.21}, 
    PlotStyle -> {Orange}, 
    PlotRange -> {{0, 0.21}, {0.045, 0.05}}, 
    PlotLegends -> {"7 beads"}], 
  ListPlot[a0b5, PlotRange -> All]]
```

which produces a graph like this

[image]

So, I used the initial guess of `a,b,c,d,ω,Φ`  to substitute into the next `FindFit`, and I've been keep repeating this step. However, the best fit I could possibly get was

[image]

Which isn't even close to desired. In addition, I have tried to modify the exponential power term of the model, `6` seemed to be the best bet.
Much appreciated if can get some help here!

Comment: Using the parameters found by `FindFit[]` as new seeds really won't do anything useful, since those parameters are a local minimum for the sum-of-squares function being optimized internally. (An analogy: consider a function with two unequal local minima, and then trying to find the lowest one by giving a starting point closer to the higher one.) You'll want to try finding better seeds even before using `FindFit[]`.

Comment: @J.M. Thanks for pinpointing that out. Any better way to find seed than keep trying? Sorry it might be a trivial question but I'm new to this

Comment: It's not really that trivial. Doesn't the theory behind the process that generated your data give hints on how you might be able to come up with rough seeds?

Comment: unfortunately not in this case, as the data are not really sequential, each data point represents Energy computed by a parameter, since the parameters are not related to each other, neither energy should. All I'm trying to do here is to plot the best fit of each set of data and combine with other plots all in one in order to find out the intersection where the optimised parameter allocates. The seed I used in the post fitted another several sets of data really well, that's why I naïvely thought it'd also work on this set.

Comment: You have fit `a0b7` and plot `a0b5`

Comment: Yes, that's a rookie mistake, really appreciate for pinpointing it out!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several problems with your posted code. First, wrapping your data in `Table` is doing no good.

```
a0b7 = 
  {{0.01`, 0.048210580093612655`}, {0.02`, 0.04823954678734667`}, 
  {0.03`, 0.04821555471430313`}, {0.04`, 0.04811564106936836`}, 
  {0.05`, 0.04815182711185681`}, {0.06`, 0.04800244159194423`}, 
  {0.07`, 0.047987407067919395`}, {0.08`, 0.04785766284608522`}, 
  {0.09`, 0.047771957661935774`}, {0.1`, 0.04772401202975343`}, 
  {0.11`, 0.0476528836847016`}, {0.12`, 0.04757077818998488`}, 
  {0.13`, 0.04752808223718771`}, {0.14`, 0.04743123828481375`}, 
  {0.15`, 0.047472879479558236`}, {0.16`, 0.04753933712481332`}, 
  {0.17`, 0.0475047868063725`}, {0.18`, 0.04757767540247086`}, 
  {0.19`, 0.04759783119112234`}, {0.2`, 0.04756174676025805`}, 
  {0.21`, 0.04762931320390573`}};

a0b7model = a Exp[-b (x - c)^6] + d Sin[ω x + Φ];
a0b7fit = FindFit[a0b7, a0b7model, {a, b, c, d, ω, Φ}, x]
```

> FindFit::cvmit: Failed to converge to the requested accuracy or precision within 100 iterations.

Next, Mathematica is telling you that it didn't get a good fit, but you neglected to mention this important fact. However, the fit isn't as bad as the one you show because you seemed to be confused about which model goes with which data set.

```
Show[
 Plot[Evaluate[a0b7model /. a0b7fit], {x, 0.01, 0.21},
  PlotStyle -> {Orange},
  PlotRange -> {{0, 0.21}, {0.045, 0.05}},
  PlotLegends -> {"7 beads"}],
 ListPlot[a0b7, PlotRange -> All]]
```

[image: plot]

Note that in my plot, everything is prefixed with "a0b7", but this does not hold in your posted code.

Comment: thanks for pinpointing it out!  I guess my updated question now is, any suggestion what seed can fit it better?

Comment: @GavyLittlewolf. Finding a better model is a math or statistics question, not a Mathematica issue. I suggest you ask on stats.SE or math.SE.

Comment: I appreciate your help. I have a question in regard to your first point, you mentioned " wrapping your data in Table is doing no good." may I ask the reason why?

Comment: @ Gavy The syntax for Table you have used is wrong. Moreover Table is mostly used for generating a list of things. Here you already have data available. So there is no need for Table.